# Strip /n from line and simultaneously do a replace in that line in Python

Tags: python, dita

I'm trying to quickly create a list of DITA keydefs from a list of document titles.
If the title is "Device User Guide", I want to create a keydef like this:

```
<keydef keys="Device_User_Guide" class="+ map/topicref mapgroup-d/keydef ">
  <topicmeta class="- map/topicmeta ">
   <keywords class"- topic/keywords ">
    <keyword class="- topic/keyword ">Device User Guide</keyword>
   </keywords>
  </topicmeta>
</keydef>
```

The titles are extracted from titles.txt file, where each of them is a new line. This causes the key (Device_User_Guide) to contain a \n at the end, so my output is this:

```
<keydef keys="Device_User_Guide
" class="+ map/topicref mapgroup-d/keydef ">
      <topicmeta class="- map/topicmeta ">
       <keywords class"- topic/keywords ">
        <keyword class="- topic/keyword ">Device User Guide</keyword>
       </keywords>
      </topicmeta>
    </keydef>
```

I managed to replace the spaces with underscores and use rstrip for the keyword, but how can I strip the newline character at the same time that I'm doing the replace operation? Here is my code:

```
title = open('titles.txt', 'r')
keydefs = open('keydefs.txt', 'w')
for line in title:
    keydefs.write('<keydef keys="%s" class="+ map/topicref mapgroup-d/keydef ">\n  <topicmeta class="- map/topicmeta ">\n   <keywords class"- topic/keywords ">\n    <keyword class="- topic/keyword ">%s</keyword>\n   </keywords>\n  </topicmeta>\n</keydef>' % (line.replace(" ","_"), line.rstrip()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Simply moved `line.rstrip()` to the beginning of the loop.

```
title = open('titles.txt', 'r')
keydefs = open('keydefs.txt', 'w')
for line in title:
    newline = line.rstrip()
    keydefs.write('<keydef keys="%s" class="+ map/topicref mapgroup-d/keydef ">\n  <topicmeta class="- map/topicmeta ">\n   <keywords class"- topic/keywords ">\n    <keyword class="- topic/keyword ">%s</keyword>\n   </keywords>\n  </topicmeta>\n</keydef>' % (newline.replace(" ","_"), newline))
```